# Is There a Way to Add Tabs in Global Fields?

Tags: plugin-development, plugins, field, globals

I see that it is not possible to add tabs to Global fields (unlike, say, with entries, where one can organize one's fields into different tab groups).

Is there a way (without editing the core files) to change this so that I can organize my global settings fields into tabbed sections?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

As far as my knowledge goes there is not a way to do this without some though changes.
Wouldn't it just be better to add another global and just name it settings?

Something like:

globalSettings(option1)

globalSettings(option2)

globalSettings(option3)

So that you organize them like that? Only thing you have to keep in mind then is when you use it in your template you have to keep track of which setting is used for what but if you name them right that wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: I can make other global settings groups, but for my use case I would prefer to use both options (i.e., multiple groups with each group having tabbed sections).

Comment: I don't think you can do that without changing some core files. I've been looking for a plugin of some sort for you but can't find any.